# PyQt4 Segmentation Fault on import

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault, pyqt4

I've installed `python-qt4`, but I'm getting a Segmentation Fault as soon as I import it.  Does anyone know what might be going wrong, or how I would further troubleshoot?  I'm not very familiar with qt.  Thanks!

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import *
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You should look at the bug reports of your Linux distro, this should never happen.

Comment: What is your OS and how have you installed it?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 17, running as a guest VM using VirtualBox on Windows 10.